# Show checkboxes that are already checked by getting the information from database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I have created a method in my asp project where I can select a garage and fill in some checkboxes that I want associated with the garage. These are stored in a database cross table. Here's the table structure:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[GarageID]
      ,[RequestProperty]
      ,[Active]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[UpdatedDate]
      ,[UpdatedBy]
  FROM [dbo].[GarageCrossRequestType]
```

Example data after checkboxes are sent:

```
ID  GarageID    RequestProperty Active  
299  64043       1                  1
```

Now, I would like these checkboxes to be crossed/checked by getting the information from the database, so for example when choosing garage with `id 64043` the box for `requestproperty` with value 1 should be checked/crossed. I have created a c# method for getting the information from the database like following:

```
public List<GarageModel> getRequestType(int garageId)
        {
            var rModel = new List<GarageModel>();
            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT GarageID, RequestProperty FROM¨
                GarageCrossRequestType WHERE GarageID = " + garageId;
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection);

                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                foreach (DataRow i in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var model = new GarageModel();
                    model.GarageId = Convert.ToInt32(i["GarageID"].ToString());
                    model.Values = Convert.ToInt32(i["RequestProperty"].ToString());

                    rModel.Add(model);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.ToString();
            }

            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }

            return rModel; 
        }
```

When debugging, this works and I get the correct values. However, *I am stuck on how I should proceed to fill the checkboxes*? I will share my code on how I send the values to the database and how I fill the checkboxes below. Here's the c# method:

```
public bool EditGarage(GarageModel model)
        {
            var valid = false;

            var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGarageEditGarage", Connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GarageId", model.GarageId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", model.Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", model.Note);
            try
            {

                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result == 1)
                    valid = true;
            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }

            // Add request types for garage when editing garage
            if (model.garageCrossRequestType != null) { 
            foreach (var item in model.garageCrossRequestType)
            { 
               var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spGarageGetRequestTypes", Connection);
               cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GarageId", model.GarageId);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestType", item);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 1);

               int result = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
               if (result == 1)
               valid = true;

            }
            }

            return valid;
        }
```

Html(Index):

```
  @foreach (var items in Model)
            {
                <style>
                    .ab{
                        margin-right: 8px;
                    }
                </style>

                <div style=" width: 40%; display: block; float: right; margin-right: 10%; margin-top: 10%;">
                    <h4>Choose request types for garage:</h4><br />
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class="rowa">
                            <label class="ab">Claim</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.Claim" id="@items.Claim" placeholder="Tires" value="1" /> <!-- values for request type -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class="rowa">
                            <label class="ab">Scheduled Service</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.ScheduledService" id="@items.ScheduledService" placeholder="Scheduled" value="2" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class="rowa">
                            <label class="ab">Tires</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.Tires" id="@items.Tires" placeholder="Tires" value="3" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class="rowa">
                            <label class="ab">Rent Replacement Car</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.RentRepalcementCar" id="@items.RentRepalcementCar" placeholder="Tires" value="4" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class="rowa">
                            <label class="ab">Other Work</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.OtherWork" id="@items.OtherWork" placeholder="Tires" value="5" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class="rowa">
                            <label class="ab">Insurance</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.Insurance" id="@items.Insurance" placeholder="Tires" value="6" />
                        </div>
                    </div><br />
                </div>
            }
```

JavaScript/Jquery:

```
$("#EditGarageBtn").click(function () {
            var customerNumber = customerNumberOfEditingGarage;
            name = $("#GarageName").val();
            countryId = $("#Country").val();
            var garageId = $("#garageId").val();
            var note = $("#Note").val();
            var email = $("#Email").val();

            var garageCrossRequestType  = $(".checkbclass:checked").map(function () {
                return $(this).val(); // to see which request types are checked
            }).toArray();
            console.log(garageCrossRequestType);

            $("#EditGarageBtn").hide();

            if (countryId == "Norway")
                countryId = 2;
            if (countryId == "Finland")
                countryId = 4;

            if (name.length > 0 && email.length > 0 && phone.length > 0 && contactperson.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditGarage", "Garage")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    garageCrossRequestType: garageCrossRequestType,
                    name: name, countryId: countryId, garageId: garageId, 
                    note: note, email: email
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "Failure") {
                        toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr["success"]("Garage successfully updated");
                        customerNumberOfEditingGarage = null;
                        refreshGrid();
                    }
                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });
            } else {
                toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
            }
        });
```

Now, I've tried doing a ajax call similar to the code above to at least get the data from the database when using `console.log`, but I can't seem to get the data from the controller to the index either. So I guess what I need help with is 1. How I can get the data that I get in my c# method to show in the view and 2. How can I connect this so that the correct checkboxes gets checked with the values? Or maybe I am completly off and there's a simpler way to do this?

Thankful for any help!

***UPDATE: So I created added this Ajax call:***

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("getRequestType", "Garage")?garageId=' + garageId,
                      dataType: 'JSON',
                      data: {
                          garageId: garageId, Values: Values
                      },
                        sucess: function (data) {
                            if (data != "Failure") {
                                //return garageId, value;
                        }
                    }
                  }); console.log(garageId, Values);
```

It works etcetera, I can see in the console log that I can get the *`garageId`* and the *`Value`*. However (lol) the problem now is that I can test for example in the model like this:

```
public int Values { get; set; } = 5;
```

which will result in showing a number 5 and the correct `garageid` when i use console log. But the values from the method `getRequestType` does not seem to connect to the model. As seen I use a `foreach loop` in the method and set `model.Values` with the database value from `RequestProperty`. So If I set the model to:

```
public int? Values { get; set; } = null;
```

for example, It will show null etcetera. So something is clearly not working correctly. I can't seem to figure out what about the method is wrong however, so again very thankful for any help!! (Classic programming solving one problem but finding another one lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think a listView works better.

and for the list of selections, use a checkBoxlist.

So we have

```
tblGarage       - our list of garages
tblitemsInGarge - list of times in each garage
tblItems        - our list of possible choices.
```

So, say this markup:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="LvGarage" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemDataBound="LvGarage_ItemDataBound" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="GarageNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GarageName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="GarageTypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GarageType") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <h4>Items in Garage</h4>
                 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckList" runat="server"
                    CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="20" 
                    DataTextField="ItemName" DataValueField="ID" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                    <hr style="border:solid;border-top:1px"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" Class="table table-hover">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">GarageName</th>
                    <th runat="server">GarageType</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <br />

     <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="btn-default" OnClick="cmdSave_Click" />
```

And we now load ListView, but for each row, we pull choices from the database.
(row data bound).

So, our code to load is thus this:

```
    DataTable rstItems = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadMyView();
    }

    public void LoadMyView()
    {
        rstItems = MyRst("SELECT ID, ItemName from tblItems ORDER BY ItemName");

        LvGarage.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * From tblGarage ORDER BY GarageName");
        LvGarage.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        var rst = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            // fill items table
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return rst;
    }
```

But, we need on Row data bind to fill out the check box list (the table of choices), and ALSO set the selected ones (from tbleItemsInGarage).

We have this:

```
    protected void LvGarage_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            CheckBoxList ckList = (CheckBoxList)e.Item.FindControl("ckList");

            ckList.DataSource = rstItems;
            ckList.DataBind();

            // now get all rows for this garage
            int ID = (int)LvGarage.DataKeys[e.Item.DataItemIndex]["ID"];
            DataTable rstItemsChecked = new DataTable();
            rstItemsChecked = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblItemsInGarage WHERE Garage_ID = " + ID);
            foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstItemsChecked.Rows)
                ckList.Items.FindByValue(OneRow["Item_ID"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

And the output is now this:

[image]

All we need now, is a single save button to send any changes you make back to the database. And that code looks like this:

```
    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvRow in LvGarage.Items)
        {
            // now get all rows for this garage
            int ID = (int)LvGarage.DataKeys[lvRow.DataItemIndex]["ID"];
            string strSQL = "SELECT ID, Item_ID, Garage_ID FROM tblItemsInGarage WHERE Garage_ID = " + ID;

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
                new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter dUpdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder sUpdate = new SqlCommandBuilder(dUpdate);
                DataTable rstItemsChecked = new DataTable();
                rstItemsChecked.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                // remove all selected
                foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstItemsChecked.Rows)
                    OneRow.Delete();

                // now add back ONLY checked items
                CheckBoxList ckList = (CheckBoxList)lvRow.FindControl("ckList");
                foreach (ListItem citem in ckList.Items)
                {
                    if (citem.Selected)
                    {
                        DataRow OneRow = rstItemsChecked.NewRow();
                        OneRow["Item_ID"] = citem.Value;
                        OneRow["Garage_ID"] = ID;
                        rstItemsChecked.Rows.Add(OneRow);
                    }
                }
                dUpdate.Update(rstItemsChecked);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now a bit of code, but not too much!!!

Using  listview, dropping in that checkBox list and DRIVING the checkbox list from the table of choices.

We get:

```
not a lot of markup
not a lot of code to load
But REALLY make gains in the database update process.
```

All in all, not a lot of code, given that we have to pull + push back the selecting from that check box list.

Comment: Wow thank you!! I'm trying the code, the only problem I have is that I get an error because "The name 'LvGarage' does not exist in the current context", but I'm trying to figure out why! This code is great I've never worked with ListViews before so thank you

Comment: hmm, the name LvGarage does not exists error does not wanna go away, any idea why this happens?

Comment: LvGarage in my code is just the name (id) of the grid view control. Not sure what that would effect this issue - you of course can name any control anything you want - but lvGarage is simply the ID of the Grid View control I used here.